# Angular 2 use property in a new function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ibeacon

I'm trying to use the beacon Minor propriety in a new function but, but the editor tells me that the name cannot be found.I know this is a rather silly questions but I just can't understand how to make it work.

This is the function:

```
listenToBeaconEvents() {
    this.events.subscribe('didRangeBeaconsInRegion', (data) => {

      // update the UI with the beacon list  
      this.zone.run(() => {

        this.beacons = [];
        let beaconList = data.beacons;
        beaconList.forEach((beacon) => {
          let beaconObject = new BeaconModel(beacon);
          this.beacons.push(beaconObject);
          console.log(beacon.minor);
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

in here, when I do `console.log(beacon.minor)` I get the expected result, but if I try to access it outside this function is not working anymore.

like this:

```
  isThatBeacon() {
   if (beacon.minor == 12345) {
     console.log('beacon found');
   }
  }
```

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Nitzan's answer I don't get an error in the editor, however, when I try it on the device I get the following error:

```
inline template:22:4 caused by: Cannot read property 'minor' of undefined
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<button class="danger" (click)="isThatBeacon()">is working?</button>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are not passing the beacon instance to your function in (click)="isThatBeacon()"..this will fails: if (beacon.minor == 12345)

Comment: You need to pass an object to `isThatBeacon` or an index, or something.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `beacon` exists only in the scope of the function passed to `beaconList.forEach`, outside of this scope the variable doesn't exist.

You have a few options, depending on what you're trying to do:

(1) Pass an index to `isThatBeacon`:

```
isThatBeacon(index: number) {
   if (this.beacons[index].minor == 12345) {
      console.log('beacon found');
   }
}
```

But you can use this method only after your async operations have finished.

(2) Pass the actual beacon to `isThatBeacon`:

```
isThatBeacon(beacon: BeaconModel) {
   if (beacon.minor == 12345) {
      console.log('beacon found');
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.I've just updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach here, to *find* a beacon based on on your value you could do the following:

```
isThatBeacon() {
   let beacon = this.beacons.find(x => x.minor === 12345)
   if(beacon != undefined) {
     console.log('beacon found!')
   } else {
     console.log('no beacon found!')
   }
}
```

If you actually want to look for a specific beacon based on some value, you can pass that value to your function and look for that value in your array.

The thought behind the below solution is for the case that you are not **always** using the static value `12345`, but the value can change and that you can check any beacons, if they exists and that is why I wanted to present this solution of finding a specific beacon. But if you do not need this functionality Nitzan's answer is surely better! :)

```
isThatBeacon(value) {
   let beacon = this.beacons.find(x => x.minor === value)
   if(beacon != undefined) {
     console.log('beacon found!')
   } else {
     console.log('no beacon found!')
   }
}
```

As to your error, that is probably caused by an async issue, that the view is rendered before the data has been retrieved. So where you list your beacons, probably in some iteration add a `*ngIf`-statement, like so:

```
<div *ngIf="beacons">
  <div *ngFor="let beacon of beacons">{{beacon.minor}}</div>
</div>
```

OR you can use the safe navigation operator:

```
<div *ngFor="let beacon of beacons">{{beacon?.minor}}</div>
```

More about the safe navigation operator [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator)

Comment: Did this solve you issue? :) If so, please consider accepting this answer, since the other answer did not solve your issue.